# QUAC atmospheric correction for Landsat-8 (ENVI 5.0)

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, landsat-8

I try to realize QUAC atmospheric correction for the band 4 and band 5 of Landsat-8 in ENVI5.0. This version doesn’t support Landsat8 (doesn’t have parameters of Landsat-8).
At the first step I glued Band3, Band4 и Band5 by Layer stacking Tool in a single file.
Then (as I understood) I need to put some parameters in this file by dint of Edit Envi Header Tool.
I put Wavelenght from the official page:
http://landsat.usgs.gov/band_designations_landsat_satellites.php

The program doesn’t know the sensor type, so it remained “Unknown”.

I don’t know any other parameters for Landsat-8 and which parameters  I need to include.
So, I realized QUAC correction. But the result of NDVI calculation was failed.

Which parameters of Landsat-8 for QUAC atmospheric correction I need to include?

Answer (score 1):

QUAC determines atmospheric correction parameters directly from the observed pixel spectra in a scene. Generally producing reflectance spectra within +/-15% of the other methods. Check the histogram and the data type of your image (float, 8 bits, etc). What was your problem with NDVI?

[image]